# Need example of INNER JOIN for 2 tables - Entity and EntityCategory - for MVC architecture

Tags: java, jdbc

I need a working example of the sample working Java web application for the MVC architecture. The technologies which are needed are only: JDBC with JSP and Servlet on, preferably MySQL. ***I don't need Hybernate and Spring.*** The sample DB may include only 2 tables like Users and UserRoles or (Products and ProductCategories, etc) which are joined on INNER JOIN.

Although a link to the sample project would be greatly appreciated, I'd also appreciate recommendations on what should I use:

1. UserRole **class** or **enum** for the sample project?
2. reference "private **UserRole** userRole;" or "private **int** userRoleId;" in **User** class?
3. as an example of the ListAllRecords method, how to utilize results of the query which joins **users** and **user_roles** tables:

   SELECT users.*, `user_roles`.`name` FROM users INNER JOIN `user_roles` ON user_role_id = `user_roles`.`id`;

Here are details of my project which I'm trying to wrap my head around:

**My design is:**

[image: Database diagram]

**Entity classes:**

```
package com.project.entity.temp;

public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private UserRole userRole;
}

public class UserRole {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

**SQL queries:**

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`user_roles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`user_roles` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user_roles` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_role_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_users_user_roles_idx` (`user_role_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_user_roles`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_role_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`user_roles` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

I follow that approach, but was wondering whether it is the proper way to accomplish the goal:

1. Got result set using this query
   SELECT users.*, user_roles.name FROM users INNER JOIN user_roles ON user_role_id = user_roles.id;
2. Looped through the records and populated UserRoles object from the ResultSet data

```
    user = new User();
    userRole = new UserRole();
    user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
    user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
    user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
    userRole.setId(resultSet.getInt("user_role_id"));
    userRole.setName(resultSet.getString("user_roles.name"));
    user.setUserRole(userRole);
```

3. When getting data from the JSP form will use the hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

Maven dependency -

> javax.persistence
> javax.persistence-api
> 2.2

Or

> javax.persistence
>     persistence-api
>     1.0.2

```
 package com.project.entity.temp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    @OneToOne
    private UserRole userRole;
}


@Entity
public class UserRole {
    

    @Id 
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    private User user; 

    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Mahesh, thank you very much for your recommendations, but unfortunately, this solution utilizes annotations which are part of the Hibernate. However, as I referenced in my original request for help, solution should not include Hibernate or Spring. Do you have something with native JDBC/JSP/Servlets/EL?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer, these are from Javax.persistence i.e JPA implementation, not from spring or hibernate packages. If you are trying to work on completely raw, then you can create your or queries using and object mapping based on result sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, again, Mahesh! Still, it is using the annotations which are related to the Hibernate. I will use the way which I followed earlier, however if anybody who can improve it are welcome to update the present thread.